# bulk account creation script not running and displaying confusing error messages

Tags: javascript, shell

I'm trying to run a script I've successfully run in the past, to create accounts. Expected result: script executes and accounts are created. Current result: script does not execute, instead gives a series of error messages that don't seem related to the content of the script (screenshot below).

[image]

The first few lines of the script are just comments, followed by imports and arg parsing (image below).
[image]

The CSV is properly formatted and the path to it is correct. As far as I know, nothing in the script has changed since the last time I ran it successfully. Scripting is not my strong suit, would deeply appreciate pointers.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add your code as text instead of images? See [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is missing a shebang. The first line of the file should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

Last time you probably explicitly ran it with `node scripts/etc/yourfile.js` instead of just `scripts/etc/yourfile.js`, which would have hidden this problem.